# Flutter app does not install (installing gets stuck) after alignment changes in Android TV?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-tv

Flutter App installed in the Android TV perfectly without the alignment changes but after I changed the alignments it does not install. Android TV version is 4.4.2. How to fix this issue?